# group concat equivalent in pig?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, apache-pig

Trying to get this done on Pig. (Looking for the group_concat() equivalent of MySQL)

In my table, for example, I have this: (3fields- userid, clickcount,pagenumber)

```
155 | 2 | 12
155 | 3 | 133
155 | 1 | 144
156 | 6 | 1
156 | 7 | 5
```

The desired output is:

```
155| 2,3,1 | 12,133,144

156| 6,7 | 1,5
```

How can I achieve this on PIG?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
grouped = GROUP table BY userid;
   X = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group as userid, 
                                table.clickcount as clicksbag, 
                                table.pagenumber as pagenumberbag;
```

Now `X` will be:

```
{(155,{(2),(3),(1)},{(12),(133),(144)},
 (156,{(6),(7)},{(1),(5)}}
```

Now you need to use the [builtin UDF BagToTuple](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.html):

```
output = FOREACH X GENERATE userid, 
                            BagToTuple(clickbag) as clickcounts, 
                            BagToTuple(pagenumberbag) as pagenumbers;
```

`output` should now contain what you want. You can merge the output step into the merge step as well:

```
    output = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group as userid, 
                     BagToTuple(table.clickcount) as clickcounts, 
                     BagToTuple(table.pagenumber) as pagenumbers;
```

Comment: I was using verstion .10. I believe the BagToTuple was available from version .11 onwards . Thanks Raze2dust.

Comment: So did you upgrade or implemented BagToTuple yourself?