# Concatenate different records in PIG script

Tags: apache-pig, concatenation, grouping

I'm trying to write a script in PIG, and what I need to do is to take a data set - that contains user id, date, country code, and other attributes... 
my wanted result is to group by user id and date, and for each group like that - to concatenate the country codes in the same field...

For example:

```
user_id |  date    | country_code
1        2017-01-01     US
1        2017-01-01     UK
1        2017-01-02     FR
2        2017-01-02     RU
2        2017-01-03     DE
2        2017-01-03     AU
```

My wanted output:

```
(1, 2017-01-01, "US,UK")
(1, 2017-01-02, FR)
(2, 2017-01-02, RU)
(2, 2017-01-03, "DE,AU")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question with very different wording actually yielded [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782255/983722) by @Hari Shankar, as the question does not appear to be a duplicate I will post the answer here directly:

> ```
> grouped = GROUP table BY userid;
>    X = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group as userid, 
>                                 table.clickcount as clicksbag, 
>                                 table.pagenumber as pagenumberbag;
> ```
>
> Now `X` will be:
>
> ```
> {(155,{(2),(3),(1)},{(12),(133),(144)},
>  (156,{(6),(7)},{(1),(5)}}
> ```
>
> Now you need to use the [builtin UDF BagToTuple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782255/983722):
>
> ```
> output = FOREACH X GENERATE userid, 
>                             BagToTuple(clickbag) as clickcounts, 
>                             BagToTuple(pagenumberbag) as pagenumbers;
> ```
>
> `output` should now contain what you want. You can merge the output
>   step into the merge step as well:
>
> ```
>     output = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group as userid, 
>                      BagToTuple(table.clickcount) as clickcounts, 
>                      BagToTuple(table.pagenumber) as pagenumbers;
> ```
>
> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18782255/983722):
>   http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.html